# How to directly upload image from heroku console to my s3 bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rails-activestorage

I have a rails API application hosted on heroku. I am able to attach images to an event item in development from the rails console like so:

```
event.image.attach(io: File.open('/path/to/file'), filename: 'file')
```

Is there a way of doing the same in production via heroku console?

Many Thanks in advance :)

Comment: For me you can do the by the same way. Do you have an error?

Comment: Yes I tried and got the following error:

irb(main):003:0> event.image.attach(io: File.open('/Users/bolad/Downloads/music.jpg'), filename: 'music')
Traceback (most recent call last):
        3: from (irb):3
        2: from (irb):3:in `open'
        1: from (irb):3:in `initialize'
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/bolad/Downloads/music.jpg)
irb(main):004:0> ›

Answer (score 0):

**You can not use a local path in heroku**

When you are in developement, your are on your local computer, so a path like `/Users/bolad/Downloads/music.jpg` make sence. On heroku, `bolad` don't exist on the system. Is for this reason you have an error.

2 solutions:

- **Use relative path**, but your need to create a folder in your project, and put your images inside. If you have a lot of image in not a good solution.
- Second solution is to **put your images on a server**, bucket amazon s3 or other. So you can access by an url, in the same way in local or production.

Comment: Thanks a lot jpheos. I hosted the images on a server and accessed it via the image url and it worked :)